# X is not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java, compilation, bukkit

I am trying to recompile a Bukkit server plugin into a JAR file. I have not changed anything significant and am 99% sure the error is not according to my changes.

I have tried to compile it using the method in the documentation on the github page of the project

This is the result of compiling the JAR file

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/charkel/Downloads/Essentials-2.x/Essentials/src/com/earth2me/essentials/craftbukkit/FakeWorld.java:[26,9] com.earth2me.essentials.craftbukkit.FakeWorld is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPluginChunkTickets() in org.bukkit.World
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for EssentialsXParent 2.17.0:
[INFO]
[INFO] EssentialsXParent .................................. SUCCESS [ 9.386 s]
[INFO] NMSProvider ........................................ SUCCESS [ 4.003 s]
[INFO] UpdatedMetaProvider ................................ SUCCESS [ 0.440 s]
[INFO] 1_8_R1Provider ..................................... SUCCESS [ 0.471 s]
[INFO] 1_8_R2Provider ..................................... SUCCESS [ 0.273 s]
[INFO] LegacyProvider ..................................... SUCCESS [ 0.195 s]
[INFO] ReflectionProvider ................................. SUCCESS [ 1.810 s]
[INFO] FlattenedProvider .................................. SUCCESS [ 0.202 s]
[INFO] EssentialsX ........................................ FAILURE [ 6.480 s]
[INFO] EssentialsXAntiBuild ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] EssentialsXChat .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] EssentialsXGeoIP ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] EssentialsXProtect ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] EssentialsXSpawn ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] EssentialsXXMPP .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.893 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-15T01:42:49+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project EssentialsX: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/charkel/Downloads/Essentials-2.x/Essentials/src/com/earth2me/essentials/craftbukkit/FakeWorld.java:[26,9] com.earth2me.essentials.craftbukkit.FakeWorld is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPluginChunkTickets() in org.bukkit.World
```

Starting line 26 as the error  refers too you find this

```
 public class FakeWorld implements World {
     private final String name;
     private final Environment env;

     public FakeWorld(String string, Environment environment) {
         this.name = string;
         this.env = environment;
```

How can I change this code to that the error disappears. Im pretty sure it would work if I can just bypass the function fully since i think i do not need this function. If I remove it other java files start complainging the funktion is missing.

The class file of org.bukkit.World that it is refering to is a part of another JAR file and should not be the issue since other JARs can compile.

Comment: You are either extending an abstract class, or implementing an interface, and forgot to implement (at least) one of the abstract methods

Comment: The code you show does not match the error. In the code, it is an abstract class, according the error, it isn't.

Comment: Made an error and added abstract because i tried if it would fix it

Comment: you need to add an implementation of the getPluginChunkTickets() method, that's it

Comment: Making it abstract is one thing (which should fix half of the error), the other thing is overriding the method as stated in the error message. Do it and try again...

Comment: When making it abstract I got worse error. Maybe the function it is trying to connect to needs to be changed but that is in the official bukkit builds jar file

Comment: I just to comile without any changes to the code and still same error. Source at https://github.com/EssentialsX/Essentials

Comment: @Charkel I've already told you twice how to solve this. Showing us a link to the entire code base won't change any of that.

Comment: I am sadly to bad at java to understand/achive it i suppose :(